# Can I still remove and upload a new apk in google play console before publish?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I haven't published this app yet, but I uploaded an APK with a critical bug in it by accident, and I want to replace it. Can I still just remove and upload a new APK?

My main two concerns is that 1) I will have to change the version code and version number somehow because Google already signed my old apk and 2) I already completed all of the content rating, descriptions, ads or no ads, etc. settings. Do I have to do them again or will there be some sort of problem there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 16 Feb 2020**

As pointed out by @tuexss in the comments, the `Artifact Library` has been replaced by `App Bundle Explorer`

**Original Answer**

You can upload a new APK with the same version code and a version number if you haven't published the old APK. All you have to do is discard the current release, go to the artifact library and delete the old APK and then create a new release from the console and upload your new APK with the same version code and version number.

If you have published the old APK, i.e., you have pressed the start rollout to production button then you need to upload a new APK with increased version code. The version number isn't mandatory to be increased in every new release although increasing it will help you track the data in a better way.

In either case, you will not have to fill out the play console details again.

Comment: This worked perfectly! For anyone reading this, note that if you change your version number between swapping the APK's the listed version name will still be based on your first APK's version name so be sure to switch that out too manually

Comment: The "artifact library" has been renamed to "App bundle explorer" in the new google play console, in case you're looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the new one, and make sure to have it 100% rollout. You can see it inside the Google Play Console once it's ready to publish. As far as I know you can't delete the apk but you can put a version on top and make sure it's the one that goes in the Store.

Comment: What does 100% rollout mean? And do I have to make the version code 2 then?

Comment: yups version code 2 so you can reference it. The 100% rollout is found inside release management -> app releases -> production track. I suggest you manage that and ensure version 2 is rolledout 100%

Comment: Thanks for your time! Kartik's answer helped me do what I wanted more, which was to keep the version code at 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes You won't find 'Delete APK/AAB' in "App Bundle Explorer" Please follow the steps to clean delete the accidentally uploaded APK/AAB.

1. Edit release -> remove AAB/APK as follows.

[image]

2. Save the Release.

[image]

3. Now the Delete button would have appeared in "App Bundle Explorer" Section.

[image]